# Continuations for Recurring Job

Tags: hangfire

Since BackgroundJob doesn't have Add/Update, I try to work my way around with Recurring job and then set a Background Continuations that will Remove Recurring after it's first time generated. But it's not only remove, but also make my recurring job generate each second after the first generated.

```
[HttpGet("{day}/{month}/{hour}/{minute}/{second}/{jobID}")]
        public string Get(int day, int month, int hour, int minute, int second, string jobID)
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobID, () => Console.WriteLine("At " + hour + " hour " + minute + " minute " +
                second + " second, day " 
                + day + " month " + month),
                "*/" + second + " " + minute + " " + hour + " " + day + " " + month + " *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(jobID, () => RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(jobID));
            return "value";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Recurring job can't goes with Backgroundjob.ContinueWith. If I want to make it work like a schedule job and still able to update time span inside, I need to set a function to remove it along side.

```
[HttpGet("{day}/{month}/{hour}/{minute}/{second}/{jobID}")]
        public string Get(int day, int month, int hour, int minute, int second, string jobID)
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobID, () => removeRecurring(jobID),
                "*/" + second + " " + minute + " " + hour + " " + day + " " + month + " *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            return "value";
        }
        public void removeRecurring(string jobId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(jobId);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved RecurringJobs not having continuations by using another job that just enqueues the parent job and continuation.

```
public class RecurringBackgroundJobs {
  public void SetRecurringJobWithContinuation(string jobName, string cronExpression) {
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate
        ( jobName
        , () => EnqueueJobWithContinuation()
        , cronExpression );
  }

  public void EnqueueJobWithContinuation() {
    BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith<ISomeOtherInterface>
        ( BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ISomeInterface>((someInstance) => someInstance.SomeFunction())
        , (someOtherInstance) => someOtherInstance.SomeOtherFunction()
        , JobContinuationOptions.OnlyOnSucceededState );
  }
}
```